# Birthday Holidays

Tags: probability

Labor laws in Erewhon require factory owners to give every worker a holiday whenever one of them has a birthday and to hire without discrimination on the grounds of birthdays. Except for these holidays, they work a 365-day year. The owners want to maximize the expected total number of man-days worked per year in a factory. How many workers do factories have in Erewhon?

The solution involves calculating the probability (for n workers) of no birthdays on day one as $(364/365)^{n}$. The author calculates the expected number of man days on the first day as $n\times(364/365)^{n}$.

Now, for $365$ days, how is the expected number of man days equating to $365\times(n)\times(364/365)^{n}$? What theorem can we apply to extrapolate the expected man days for day $1$ to $365$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The question states:  “give *every worker* a holiday whenever one of them has a birthday” (emphasis added).  I believe that answers your question.

Comment: Does this stupid law actually hold there ? Or is it just a fantasy exercise ?